# in python why isnt the program letting me import data from the user

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the data from the user and then print the month's calendar why isnt my code exporting anything
note I have to keep or rather use `def printCalender()`

```
import calendar

def printCalender():
    month=int(input("please enter month date and year hit enter after each digit is placed: "))
    day=int(input())
    year=int(input())
    print(calendar.sunday(month,day,year))
```

Answer (score 2):

if you look at your input statements - youre casting them the wrong way:

you do `month = input(int())`

where as you should be doing `month = int(input())`

as per comments --> 
once this is done make sure to call `printCalender()`

your code should work once you make these changes.

Comment: when i sumbit the code it runs and theres no output of anything

Comment: Thats because you are not calling the function perhaps - at the end of your code add `printCalender()` ----- make sure its outside you function

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import calendar


def printCalender():
    month=int(input("please enter month date and year hit enter after each digit is placed: "))
    day=int(input())
    year=int(input())
    print(calendar.month(year, month, day))


printCalender()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this`. All you need is year & month. Date not needed

```
def printCalender():
    month=int(input("please enter month and year hit enter after each digit is placed: "))
    year=int(input())
    print(calendar.month(year,month))


printCalender()
```

**Output**

```
please enter month and year hit enter after each digit is placed: 6
2012
     June 2012
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see you are not actually running the function. Try this:

```
import calendar

def printCalender():
    month=int(input("please enter month date and year hit enter after each digit is placed: "))
    day=int(input())
    year=int(input())
    print(calendar.sunday(month,day,year))

printCalender()
```